# Chrome displaying white overlay on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Our company's website (http://latitudesign.net) was working correctly this morning and loading the text animation and background slider (backstretch.js). However, after updating the site's logo, the website now is hidden behind a white background and as it is resized, the body of the website becomes visibly again. Any ideas? I have tried reverting to previous state of site however to no avail. It seems to only happen on Chrome, not seeing the problem on any other browsers including mobile.

Code running the page's load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.



     $.backstretch([
 "images/13.jpg",
 "images/34.jpg",
 "images/44.jpg",
 "images/AIG_interior.gif",
 "images/30.jpg",
 "images/31.jpg",
 "images/32.jpg",
 "images/42.gif",
 "images/35.jpg",
 "images/36.jpg"
], {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 2700

}); 




    })
//]]>
```

Could anything I changed in the CSS cause this to happen?

Comment: We're not mind readers; please post your code.

Comment: From the console on Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://latitudesign.net/css/jplayer.css. Can't do much more without some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the host or from you .htaccess,

seems like this file is missing and instead of this appears a not found page. A solution will be just to create this file or to remove the html line linked to it.

Comment: I removed the link to the css file that was missing however it hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need position:relative on the backstretch.

```
<div class="backstretch" style="[...]position: relative;">
```

Comment: I tried adjusting to relative positioning and that corrected the positioning of the menu bar being hidden, but it did not remove the white overlay that is covering the background slider. Is it possible I could have messed up the css on the white header that is holding the logo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the animate.css...I removed it and now its working correctly.